# Angular component css not added to <head>

Tags: css, angular

I have an Angular 11 component -- app-progress that includes some css. It's in a separate npm package. Testing it within its own project shows the correct styles are applied.

In another Angular 11 app I'm importing that app-progress component. I've checked the compiled fesm2015 js file and it definitely includes the css:

```
styles: ["[_nghost-%COMP%]{background-color:#d4d4d4;border-radius:0}.narrow[_nghost-%COMP%]{height:8px!important}"]
```

However when I add the  to the HTML it renders the correct HTML but the CSS is not added to the `<head>` section and the `<app-progress>` doesn't have an _nghost... attribute added to it.

Any ideas what might be happening?

Comment: did you find an answer? I am experiencing the same problem

Comment: I did not yet. It's really weird.

Comment: After finally getting some time to focus on this, my issue was unfortunately due to other members of the team creating two separate versions of the same component in two git repos without letting me know and I was using the "old" version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may happen when @angular-devkit/build-angular version doesn't match the rest of the angular packages.

In my case my @angular-devkit/build-angular package was at v13.2.5 whereas all my other packages were mostly 13.1.1.

Once I updated all my angular packages to 13.2.6, no more style issues.

I also tried to replicate the issue after the update, but no luck...

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer in case anyone else runs across your issue and ends up here.

Answer (score 0):

Things learned since the last answer:

So we occasionally have css issues upon build of our (large) project. What we found over time is that something broken gets cached on compilation. What it exactly is, we're not sure, but once we delete the cache and rebuild, things work again.

Find the angular cache at "{project root (where package.json is)}/.angular"

Try deleting the cache folder inside, or the entire .angular folder, since all that's in there is the cache folder anyway.